# Why .rstrip() sometimes works but sometimes not?

Tags: python, string

I'm a beginner just start learning Python.
I have read the documentation for `rstrip` and some other questions here, but still get confused about how `rstrip` exactly works.

I could understand how string.rstrip() works, such as:

```
INPUT:      '   spacious   '.rstrip()
OUTPUT:     '   spacious'
```

Also understand this:

```
INPUT:      "ABBA".rstrip("AB") 
OUTPUT:     ''
```

But get confused for the following:

```
INPUT:     "AABAA".rstrip("A")
OUTPUT:    'AAB'
```

Question for this one is why its output is `AAB` rather than `B`? Since I feel `AA` at the beginning of the string and `AA` at the end of the string are both combinations of `A`

And also for this one:

```
  INPUT:     "ABCABBA".rstrip("AB")
  OUTPUT:    'ABC'
```

Question for this one is why its output is not `C`? My thought is `AB` at the beginning, `AB` in the middle, `BA` at the end should all be stripped.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: You understand `'   spacious   '.rstrip()` but not `'ABC'`? What do you think the `r` stands for in the name? Is there something in the documentation that is confusing?

Comment: I was expecting this to be one of the many instances where people don't realize that the argument is a set of characters to strip instead of a suffix to remove if present, but this is a surprise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MadPhysicist :)! I think I understand why now. r stands for right so it is a method to removing characters from “right” side of the string. Once it meets a character not in the character combinations you gave, (for example: C in ABCABBA), it stops. So the output is ABC rather than C. Is this logic correct?

Comment: @Cloudy_Green. Bingo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's work with what you understand, and get you to what you don't.

```
INPUT:      '   spacious   '.rstrip()
OUTPUT:     '   spacious'
```

Here, the `rstrip()` function is taking your string and removing all of the unwanted characters from the back.  (`rstrip` is different from `strip` in that rstrip is **reversed** - it starts from the back.)  In this case, you haven't passed any string indicating what to strip away, so it defaults to "all whitespace."  So, what it's doing is starts at the back of the string, and removes all whitespace.  It stops as soon as it hits non-white-space, which is why the results is `'   spacious'`.

Moving on, what's happening here?

```
INPUT:     "AABAA".rstrip("A")
OUTPUT:    'AAB'
```

Here, you're passing an argument to rstrip.  The string is a list of all of the things to strip away.  In this case, `"A"` is telling it to strip away *only* the letter A from the back of the string.  Like the previous example, rstrip **stops as soon as it hits a character that isn't something to throw out**.  Consequently, it stops on the "B", just like the previous rstrip stopped on the rightmost letter `s`.

That should make the final example make sense.  Here,

```
INPUT:     "ABCABBA".rstrip("AB")
OUTPUT:    'ABC'
```

you are telling rstrip to remove any trailing `A` or `B` from the string.  So it does, and **stops at the first character that you're not stripping**, which in this case is the `C`.  As usual, once it stops, it leaves everything to the left the way it was.

Comment: **"rstrip stops as soon as it hits a character that isn't something to throw out"** is worth highlighting

Comment: Thank you so much @Scott Mermelstein for such detailed explanation step by step! :) I really appreciate that! This is exactly the problem I met and struggle with. My logic is crystal clear now after reading your post - this is super helpful! I know this question is really newbie, I really did a lot of search but still can't figure out why. Again, thank you for taking time to answer my question! You have a great weekend! :)

Comment: @Cloudy_Green Sure thing - good practice to learn _why_ things do what they do. Learn on.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Scott's answer, the key is here: `rstrip(CHARS)` **stops as soon as it hits a character that isn't in `CHARS`**. Few examples to better illustrate; suppose `txt = "banana,,,ssqqqww..."`. Then,

```py
print(txt.rstrip(",.qsw")) # 'r' for 'reverse'
# banana

print(txt.rstrip("qws.,")) # ORDER doesn't matter
# banana

print(txt.rstrip("A,.qsw")) # txt is compared against CHAR, not CHAR against txt
# banana

print(txt.rstrip("a,.qsw")) # stops at 'n', doesn't proceed to other 'a's
# banan
```

Comment: I think “r” is for “right”, to complement the “l” for “left” in `lstrip`. Unless that “l” means “leading” or something surprising...